# Network management in a test bench environnement

Tags: networking, ip, switch, vlan

I have to manage networking of a test bench, the compenent of the test bench :

- Supervisory pc on Windows
- Switch NETGEAR GS108Ev3 with 8 ports
- 6 Embedded devices with same fixed ip (i can't modify anything)

[Achitecture of test bench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xbIm.png)

I give an adress ip to supervisory ip like : 198.18.42.2
In the embedded devices a tcp server socket is waiting for a client in port 6666, and in the supervisory pc a client socket is developped to communicate.

To differentiate between devices, i created VLANS in the switch.
[table of vlans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG7QW.png)

now, every device is in his own vlan with the supervisory pc but how can i know wich devices i'm communicating with ?
IS there a solution to communication with a specific vlan or a specif switch ports ?

Answer (score 1):

VLANs alone won't fix your duplicate IP problem, and there are more steps to creating VLANS than simply turning them on in your switch.

If you want to be able to talk to all devices at the same time, you need to hide each of the duplicate IPs behind unique IPs. Something like a separate NAT for each VLAN may do the trick. You'll need an appropriate enterprise grade router to do this.

I believe you have enabled the 802.1Q VLAN tagging feature in your switch. You have not configured which VLAN your supervisory PC is on. This leads to the second solution. If you only need to talk to one device at a time, you can switch the VLAN tag on the network interface of your supervisor machine to select the VLAN you'd like to be on. It would be a setting inside 'change adapter settings'. You can also do this by switching the port tag setting on your switch so that it tags traffic coming from your supervisor PC.